# Debug slow "git pull" operation executed by the Local System account on a Windows Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, php, apache-2.4, git

On a Windows server, which runs Apache and PHP, the webserver executes a `git pull` through a PHP script. This is part of a deployment process.

When the Apache2 service runs under the Local System account, the `exec("git pull")` in PHP is extremely slow, and sometimes never completes. When it runs as Administrator, this is not the case.

Git operations other than the pull are not slow at all. Therefore, I'm suspecting some SSH/network problems are at stake. However, I'm unaware of a way to debug this.

Therefore, how does one find the cause to this issue? Or, any suggestions for the possible causes?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue when running the salt-minion as "Local System" account on Windows. It has something to do with git itself when running as that user. Git is trying to do something which times out. The actual command succeeds, but is slowed down by whatever is timing out. It's a git issue.

Comment: Thanks, so how do you know that it is Git to blame? - in that case I'd like to file a bug report.

Comment: You can get the same behavior if you run a PowerShell script to run as the local system account and run the same git commands